# Qt C++ - Creation QList<Myclass> - is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have just started with C++ Qt and I wrote the following .h file: The .cpp file contains only empty constructors and destructors.

```
#include <QList>

class XML_Files
{

public:
    XML_Files();
    ~XML_Files();

protected:
    QList<Myclass> m_Xmls;

};


class Myclass
{
public:
    Myclass();
    ~Myclass();

protected:

    int a;

};
```

but I keep getting the following errors:

```
error C2065: 'Myclass': undeclared identifier
error C2923: 'QList': 'Myclass' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
```

What do I have to do to declare a `Qlist` with my own data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the name `MyClass` until the compiler knows about it.  Since you do not declare `MyClass` until after `XML_Files` you cannot use it's name in `XML_Files`.

The simplest solution here is to just change the order of the declarations and declare `MyClass` before `XML_Files`.

Comment: Ahh... I have searching this on google for 1-2 hours and i have found nothing... I have never expected that solution is so trivial. Thanks you very much you both of you @Alex and NathanOliver. You were first you have accepted answer :)

Comment: @ErikŠťastný No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to fix this, is to turn the order of both classes. However there is a second solution, if this is not desired or possible:

You may declare `Myclass` before defining it. Then compilation will succeed.

```
#include <QList>

class Myclass;

class XML_Files
{

public:
    XML_Files();
    ~XML_Files();

protected:
    QList<Myclass> m_Xmls;

};


class Myclass
{
// ...
};
```

Comment: Ahh... I have searching this on google for 1-2 hours and i have found nothing... I have never expected that solution is so trivial. Thanks you very much you both of you Alex and @NathanOliver.